# How to bend a closed mesh spherically?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, shrinkwrap, project

I want to project a mesh onto a spherical surface. For this I use the ShrinkWrap modifier. With the edge it works very well. But it doesn't work with the face because I can't generate a grid.

1. Draw a flat closed Bezier Curve
2. Convert to mesh
3. Fill mesh

a. Grid Fill doesn't work here because the vertices are irregularly distributed.

b. I can't draw edges manually because I need vertices at the intersection points. I don't know about that, especially when I have > 100 intersections.

4. Project the mesh onto a UV Sphere using ShrinkWrap modifier.

[image]

Can someone give me a tip to solve the puzzle or to simplify it? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Knife Project* tool. First fill your face:

[image]

Create another object (a plane), subidivide it, delete the faces only, put it over the first object:

[image]

Select your first object, switch to *Edit* mode, select the plane with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>, then header menu > *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

Now your object has a topology that can be bent:

[image]

Comment: Great that helped me really!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for this originally, but here would be a solution using *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

First I convert the curve into a mesh and extrude it upwards.

At the same time I use `Object Info` to get the sphere and mark its faces with a boolean value and the node `Capture Attribute`.

Then I use `Mesh Boolean` to cut the previously extruded object.

After that `Separate Geometry` can be used to separate the part of the intersection.

Finally, only the edges adjacent to more than one face have to be removed.

---

If you want to keep the generated area instead, you can solve it this way:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: quellenform: Thanks for your proposal, but I have no experience with Geo Nodes. Maybe its time to start with them...

Comment: @PowerNow It's never too late for *Geometry Nodes*! ;-)